# The Target Table is not Updatable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
 UPDATE (SELECT user_id,method_id FROM User AS U
                JOIN Address AS A 
                  ON A.user_id=U.id
                JOIN Shipping AS S 
                  ON S.address_id= A.id  WHERE user_id=1) AS T
 SET T.method_id=5;
```

and I get error "The target table T of the UPDATE is not updatable". How can I change my query to update the column from the sub-query? Any explanation would be great
I'm using MySQL

Comment: `UPDATE` needs a *real* table, not the result of a subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Shipping s
JOIN Address AS a ON s.address_id = a.id
SET s.method_id = 5
WHERE a.user_id = 1
```

There's no need to join with the `User` table, since `user_id` is in the `Address` table. If you really do need to check that the user exists before updating, it can be:

```
UPDATE Shipping s
JOIN Address AS a ON s.address_id = a.id
JOIN User AS u ON a.user_id = u.id
SET s.method_id = 5
WHERE u.id = 1
```

Comment: The `JOIN` with `User` may be needed to make sure that the user exists and it's not an orphaned row.

Comment: That should be done using a foreign key constraint. I suspect it's not relevant to whether `method_id` should be updated or not.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was just sayin' :)

Comment: Fair enough, I added back the query with the extra join.